# junit reload classes

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, powermock

I use powermock to mock Logger.getInstance() method. This causes a problem as junit seems not to reload classes and after the first test test class has wrong logger instance.

```
public class LoggedClass {
    public static Logger log = Logger.getInstance();
    ....
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ LoggedClass.class, Logger.class })
public class SomeTests {
    private Logger log;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(Logger.class);
         log = PowerMockito.mock(Logger.class);
         PowerMockito.when(Logger.getInstance()).thenReturn(log);

         PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggedClass.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
         assertTrue(LoggedClass.log == log);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() { // fails
         assertTrue(LoggedClass.log == log);
    }
}
```

Test fails as LoggedClass has outdated log instance. I could inject explicitly new logger instance, but that is cumbersome when there are lots of static variables that needs to be mocked.

How can I set junit to reload classes every time it runs new test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the second test fails is that you are creating a new instance of `log` in your `@Before` method for each test but since the call to `Logger.getInstance()` is `static` it is only happening once. Consider doing what you have in `@Before` in a `@BeforeClass`.

There does not seem to be a reason to create a new instance of `log` for each test. It is a `mock` and can therefore just be reset.

Comment: I thought about that, but I do not want to have log mock to be shared among tests.

Comment: just reset it. That is the same effect as creating a new one.